# Single selection of items from different groups in a menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer which is comprised of 3 groups. 
When I choose an item from another group the item from the previous group is still marked as checked even though I have code which sets it to being unchecked (and from the debugger I know that code is reached). 
How can I ensure single selection of an item?

**drawer.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group
    android:id="@+id/first_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_trips"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_trips"
        android:title="@string/menu_my_trips" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/interactive_demo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_demo"
        android:title="@string/menu_interactive_demo" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/email_support"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_support"
        android:title="@string/menu_email_support" />      
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/second_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:title="@string/menu_faq" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/user_agreement"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_description"
        android:title="@string/menu_user_agreement" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/third_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_input"
        android:title="@string/menu_logout" />
</group>
```

main_activity.java

```
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    int numOfItems = navigationView.getMenu().size();

                    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; ++i){

                        MenuItem currentItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i);
                        if (currentItem.isChecked())
                            currentItem.setChecked(false);

                    }

                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.my_trips:

                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution: setting the other groups to be uncheckable brings the desired result.

```
    private void setMenuItemCheck(MenuItem menuItem){

    int currentGroupId = menuItem.getGroupId();
    ArrayList<Integer> allGroupsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
        add(R.id.first_group);
        add(R.id.second_group);
        add(R.id.third_group);
    }};

    for (int i = 0; i < allGroupsIds.size(); ++i){

        if (currentGroupId == allGroupsIds.get(i)) {
            mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(allGroupsIds.get(i), true, true);
        } else{
            mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(allGroupsIds.get(i), false, true);
        }
    }

    menuItem.setChecked(true);

}
```